# xpath problem for importing into google sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets

I have a problem in importing one cell of a web page table into google sheets. if I cut the xpath; it imports entire row indistinguishable like this:

EarningsPerShareAfterTaxسود (زیان) خالص هر سهم– ریال۸۰۸۰۰۳

the formula that I use is:

```html
=IMPORTXML("http://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=M5h5Z2UhIZrScwDbGVf19w%3d%3d&rt=0&let=6&ct=0&sheetId=1","//*[@id='ctl00_lblYearEndToDate']")
```

But I do not want this. For example I want just **one cell** of the table of this link:
[the web-page](http://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=M5h5Z2UhIZrScwDbGVf19w%3D%3D&rt=0&let=6&ct=0&sheetId=1)

I want Second (right-to-left) column's EarningsPerShareAfterTax (second row from bottom) which is "۸۰"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language (Farsi?) is right-to-left ordered, right?

So let's get the second last `tr` and the second (actually the third) `td`:

```
//tr[last()-1]/td[3]
```

I noticed there is linebreak or so in the output. We can use INDEX to limit the result to the actual value:

```
=Index(IMPORTXML("http://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=M5h5Z2UhIZrScwDbGVf19w%3d%3d&rt=0&let=6&ct=0&sheetId=1","//tr[last()-1]/td[3]"), 2)
```